# Activityで共通データの管理のやり方について

Tags: android

Activityで共通のデータを管理するため以下のようなクラスを作成して行っています。

```
public final class CommonData {

  public static String data1;
  public static String data2;
  public static String data3;

}
```

アプリをバッググラウンドに移動し、他アプリを起動してアプリに戻ると、
Activityが破棄されていて、さらにstatic変数もnullになり、アプリが強制終了します。
メモリが不足するとOSが勝手にActivityを破棄するのだと思いますが、
static変数まで破棄するとは思いませんでした。

アプリで共通データの管理のやり方はどういった方法がありますでしょうか？

どうかアドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プリファレンス、ファイル、またはデータベースへ保存する方法をお勧めします。件数が少なければプリファレンスが一番良いでしょう。

プリファレンスは内部でxmlファイルとしてストレージに保存されるため、メモリ不足になってもデータが消えません。

Comment: プリファレンスが一番良いとのこと承知しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4):

AndroidOSではしばらく使われていないActivity(すでに完了されたであろうユーザ作業のActivity)を破棄するActivity管理がなされています。ただし、このケースはプロセスごとkillするものではありません。

static変数が初期化されているのはActivityの破棄によるものではなく、メモリ管理の観点でAndroidOSが重要でないと判断したプロセスをkillすることが原因です。
このあたりは下記のページに詳しく記されています。
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

アプリで共通のデータを管理する際には、データのライフサイクルも合わせて考えることをおススメします。
アプリケーションプロセスに閉じたライフサイクルであればApplicationクラスに共通データを持たせたり, オンメモリデータベースでキャッシュさせたりといった方法もあります。
プロセスをまたぐものの、一時的な永続化でよければcacheディレクトリを使用するなども考えられます。ActivityのライフサイクルをまたぐものであればSavedInstanceStateも採用できます。
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

永続化のための方法は色々とあります。最低限のことは下記のページにまとめられています。
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

プリファレンスはプリファレンスに最適な用途があるので、件数で選ぶより保存されるデータの性質や用途にあわせて、選択されたほうがよいかと思います。

Comment: 最初、共通データをただのclassにstatic変数に持たせていたんですが、Applicationクラスに移してもstatic変数が初期化されました。
プロセスが破棄されたので、static変数が初期化されたんですね。
プロセスが破棄された場合は、アプリが再起動するのではなく、画面遷移していたら途中のActivityから再開されます。そういうものなんですね。
勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。